# How to allow AUTO height in Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(); Function?

Tags: magento-1.9, image

How to allow AUTO height in resize function?

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize();
```

Comment: You may be interested in this great free tool as well: https://github.com/reinos/Magento-AdaptiveResize

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(600,null);
```

Using this width will be 600px and the height will auto adjust to aspect ratio.

Please up-vote and mark as answer if helpful. Thanks

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as accepted, if it helped.? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try & check:**

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(600,null);
```

**600 = Your image width** & **null is height**

Comment: I tired, But no any effect.